# Page auto scrolls upon clicking an element

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver, web-testing, chrome-web-driver

Hi guys i really cant find why page auto scrolls when i click on a textbox

```
def launchBrowser():
   options =ChromeOptions()
   options.add_argument("window-size=1280,1024")
   options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
   driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(),options=options)
   driver.get("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
   return driver 
driver = launchBrowser()
by_xpath = driver.find_element_by_xpath
```

Above is the options that i used for the browser. I use Chrome driver manager with Python selenium.

the problem that iam facing is, When I click the element to send keys the page automatically scrolls up.

Below is the code that i scripted.

```
time.sleep(2)
toClear = by_xpath("//*[contains(@placeholder ,'Weight')]");
toClear.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + "a");
toClear.send_keys(Keys.DELETE);
by_xpath("//*[contains(@placeholder ,'Weight')]").send_keys(120)
```

I face the auto scroll when i try to click the below element and i also tried to scroll down.

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 800)")
time.sleep(2)
by_xpath("//*[contains(@placeholder ,'L')]").click()
toClear = by_xpath("//*[contains(@placeholder ,'L')]");
toClear.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + "a");
toClear.send_keys(Keys.DELETE);
by_xpath("//*[contains(@placeholder ,'L')]").send_keys(45)
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong
Do consider the code as an single entity

Comment: What is the `by_xpath` function, can you share it?

Comment: by_xpath = driver.find_element_by_xpath